# Visualforce table for aggregate result grouped by CreatedBy.Name

Tags: visualforce, soql, pageblocktable, aggregateresult, group-by

I'm trying to create a custom report table in Visualforce based on an aggregate result retrieved by the SOQL:

```
SELECT CreatedBy.Name, Description, SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2), SUM(Value3) FROM Object__c  WHERE Location = M AND Date = 2021-07-20 00:00:00 GROUP BY CreatedBy.Name, Description.
```

I need to show the result as following:

[image]

I need to show all records for each name without repeating the name.

I'm using this code in VF:

```
    <apex:page id="ObjVF" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf" language="it-IT" controller="OBJController">
    
    Data: {!filterDate} Sede: {!location}
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!object}" var="ing" title="Vendite" columns="5" align="center" border="2px"  rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">>
                  
        <apex:facet name="header">Report</apex:facet>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">CreatedBy.Name</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ing['name']}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ing['descr']}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">Sum of value 1</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="€ {!ing['value1']}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">Sum of value 2</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="€ {!ing['value2']}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">Sum of value 3</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="€ {!ing['value3']}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header">Record count</apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="€ {!ing['records']}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And got this result:

[image]

Can someone help me, please?